# What is Arisa's status at the end of Guilty Crown?

Tags: guilty-crown

Arisa is shot several times by the GHQ soldiers at the end of the series, when her shield fails due to all voids disappearing, but the wiki pages have confusing information about her whereabouts at the end.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Guilty_Crown_characters) has "She follows Gai to the final battle, holding back the UN forces with her shield, and is alive seen being outside of the falling GHQ."

Is she alive? When the scene of her alive outside the building happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arisa can be seen outside of the collapsing GHQ building at around 20:23 of episode 22.

[image]

<sup>Screenshot courtesy of [Hakase](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/191/hakase)</sup>

It is not known how she got out of the collapsing GHQ building with the bullet wound she got from the UN Military Forces at 18:15, though. My guess is that she got rescued by the UN Forces, probably as an act of humanity.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Guilty Crown Wikia](http://guiltycrown.wikia.com/wiki/Arisa_Kuhouin), she is still alive, and I believe the scene of her being outside of the building is near the end of the last episode.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot? I checked both wikis before posting the question, so wikia alone is not enough.